# Specific value from http response content c#

Tags: c#, content-type, httpresponsemessage

I was wondering how can I extract a specific value from a http response content. Let's say the page from which I am making a getAsync request give back the response and in that response I need to extract the value of the passwird. How can I get the value of the password of the website inside this getAsync method?

here is the my code:

```
  async static void DownloadPage(string url)
    {
        CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
        HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html").Result)
            {

                HttpHeaders headers = response.Headers;
                HttpContent content = response.Content;
                string myContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();



            }

        }
```

this is the response I get back:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lte IE 8]><html id="reset" class="ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html id="reset" class="ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html id="reset"><!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!--><html id="reset"><!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <title>Kijiji Canada | Free local classifieds</title>
    <link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="//ca.classistatic.com/static/V/2918.2/img/kijijiFavicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"/>
    <link rel="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/+KijijiCanada" />
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Kijiji"/>
    <meta property="og:country-name" content="Canada"/>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

<meta name="msvalidate.01" content="E03E7C8B4B4E1A0234A8D2042FD326E8" />

<meta name='yandex-verification' content='79bdb66f55dcb3ee' />

    <meta name="google" content="nositelinkssearchbox">

    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en">

 ad Here</span></h4></a></li>
        <li class="ie"><a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/internet-explorer/download-ie" target="_blank"><h4>Internet Explorer<span>Download Here</span></h4></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<![endif]-->

<header class="">
            <div id="TopHeader">
        <div id="HeaderLeft">
            <a href="/" id="Logo" target="_self" title="Kijiji"></a>
            <div id="AdCount">
                Over <span id="AdCountNumber">7,479,986</span> Free Local Classifieds</div>
        </div>

        <div id="HeaderRight">
            <ul id="HeaderRightTop">
                <li><a id="SignInLink" href="/t-login.html" rel="nofollow">Sign In</a></li>
                        <li><a id="register" href="/t-user-registration.html" rel="nofollow">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/" rel="nofollow">Help Desk</a></li>

                <li><a id="ChangeLocale" rel="nofollow" href="javascript:void(0);">Français</a></li>
                </ul>

            <div id="HeaderRightBottom">
                <a id="PostAdLink" class="button-open post-ad-begin first" href="/p-select-category.html" data-btn-loc="header" rel="nofollow">
                    Post Ad</a><a class="button-header-nav last" href="/m-my-ads.html" rel="nofollow">
                My Kijiji</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        </div>
<div id="HeaderBar">
                <div id="BrowseContainer">
    <div class="text">
        Browse Categories</div>
    <div class="action"><div></div></div>

    <div id="BrowseCategoriesList" class="drop-down">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/b-buy-sell/canada/c10l0" class="category-selected" data-id="10">buy and sell</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-services/canada/c72l0" class="category-selected" data-id="72">services</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-cars-vehicles/canada/c27l0" class="category-selected" data-id="27">cars &amp; vehicles</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-pets/canada/c112l0" class="category-selected" data-id="112">pets</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-vacation-rentals/c800l0" class="category-selected" data-id="800">vacation rentals</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-community/canada/c1l0" class="category-selected" data-id="1">community</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-real-estate/canada/c34l0" class="category-selected" data-id="34">real estate</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-jobs/canada/c45l0" class="category-selected" data-id="45">jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-canada/l0?ad=wanted" class="" data-id="1000000">Want Ads</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-canada/l0?ad=offering&price-type=free" class="" data-id="1000001">Free Stuff</a></li>
            <li><a href="/b-canada/l0?price-type=swap-trade" class="" data-id="1000002">Swap / Trades</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="SearchFormContainer">
    <form id="SearchForm" action="/b-search.html">
        <label class="search-input" for="SearchInput">Search</label>

        <div id="SearchContainer">
            <input type="hidden" id="SearchLocationId" name="locationId"
                   value="0"/>
            <input type="hidden" value=""
            name="categoryId" id="SearchCategoryValue"/>
            <input type="hidden" id="ASOtherLang" value="fr_CA"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="formSubmit" value="true"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="urgentOnly" value="false"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="highlightOnly" value="false"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="gpTopAd" value="false"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="hpGallery" value="false"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="minPrice" value=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="maxPrice" value=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="adType" value=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="adPriceType" value=""/>
            <input type="hidden" name="sortByName" value="dateDesc"/>
            <div class="active" id="InputContainer">
                <input id="SearchInput" type="text" name="keywords" autocomplete="off" autofocus value="">
                <div id="InputClear"><div>X</div></div>
                <div id="SuggestedSearchesContainer" class="drop-down"></div>
                    </div>
        </div>

        <div id="SearchInContainer">
            <label>in</label>
            <div class="action" id="SearchGoButton">GO</div>
            <div id="SearchIn">
                <div id="SearchCategorySelected">
                    All Ads</div>

                <div id="SearchInList" class="drop-down">
                    <ul>
                        <li class="search-category-entry">
                            <a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="0">All Ads</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="10">
                                buy and sell</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="72">
                                services</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="27">
                                cars &amp; vehicles</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="112">
                                pets</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="800">
                                vacation rentals</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="1">
                                community</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="34">
                                real estate</a>
                            </li>
                        <li class="search-category-entry"><a class="c-lnk-mslctbx" href="#" id="45">
                                jobs</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="LocationPickerContainer">
    <label>
                My Location<strong>&nbsp;Canada</strong>
            </label>
        </div>



</div>
        </header>
    <div id="MessageContainer">
        </div>

    <div class="layout-0 fixed-width top-space bottom-space">
        <div class="layout-2">
            <div class="col-2">
                <div class="container-info bottom-space">
                    <h2>Register an account</h2>
                    <p>Make it easier to manage & post Ads.</p>
                    <a href="/t-user-registration.html">
                        <button id="RegisterButton" class="button-open next">Register Now<span class="arrow-next"></span></button>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="container-info">
                    <h2>Don&#39;t have an account?</h2>
                    <p>Manage your ads using just your email address.</p>
                    <ul class="bullet-list">
                        <li><a href="/p-select-category.html" class="post-ad-begin" data-btn-loc="login">Post an Ad</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/m-ad-digest-mail.html">Promote your Ads</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/m-ad-digest-mail.html">Edit your Ad</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/m-ad-digest-mail.html">Remove your Ad</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/m-watch-list.html" id="MyWatchlist">My Watchlist</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="container-admin">
                    <div class="container-info">
                        <form id="login-form" class="special track-form-flow" data-action-title="UserLogin" action="/t-login.html" method="post"><input type="hidden" id="" name="ca.kijiji.xsrf.token" value="1470364908850.173dd2f5deb987261b6cfc4c4f5dad22" />
<div class="circles">
                                <h1>Sign In</h1>
                                <input id="targetUrl" name="targetUrl" type="hidden" value="L15udS9JWHhHMURBNmdjdkFuTFJJeUR3PT0-"/><section>
                                    <label for="LoginEmailOrNickname">
                                        Email Address or Nickname:</label>
                                    <input id="LoginEmailOrNickname" name="emailOrNickname" req="req" type="text" value="" maxlength="128"/><span class="field-message" data-for="LoginEmailOrNickname"></span>
                                    </section>


                                <section>
                                    <label for="login-password">
                                        Password:</label>
                                    <input id="login-password" name="password" req="req" type="password" value="" maxlength="64"/><span class="field-message" data-for="login-password"></span>
                                    <a id="LoginForgottenPassword" href="/t-forgot-password.html">
                                        Forgot your password?</a>
                                </section>

                                <section class="input-offset">
                                    <label>
                                        <input id="login-rememberMe" name="rememberMe" class="ext-uncheck" type="checkbox" value="true" checked="checked"/><input type="hidden" name="_rememberMe" value="on"/>Keep me signed in</label>
                                </section>

                                <button id="SignInButton" class="button-task" type="submit">Sign In</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="fb-login disabled">
                                <p><strong>Did you register for Kijiji through Facebook?</strong></p>
                                        <p>Our Facebook log in has been disabled to make way for a more customized experience on Kijiji. To log in you must change your password. <a href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/basics/facebook-login-removal" target="_blank">Learn More</a></p>
                                        <p><a href="/t-forgot-password.html">Change your password</a></p>
                                    </div>
                        </form><p class="safety-message">
                            <strong>Protect your account:</strong>
                            Ensure that whenever you sign in to Kijiji, the Web address in your browser starts with https://www.kijiji.ca/</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div> 
          <div class="fes-pagelet">
            <div id=footer><div id="Footer" class="container--jss-0-703" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc"><div class="innerWrapper--jss-0-704" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0"><div id="FooterLinkColumns" class="container--jss-0-680" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0"><div data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0"><div class="column--jss-0-681" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10"><h3 class="columnTitle--jss-0-682" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.0">Kijiji Information</h3><ul class="columnList--jss-0-683" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1"><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.0"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/policies/kijiji-terms-of-use" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.0.0">Terms of Use</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.1"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/policies/kijiji-privacy-policy" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.1.0">Privacy Policy</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.2"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/policies/" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.2.0">Posting Policy</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.3"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.kijijiforbusiness.ca" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.3.0">Advertise with Us</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.4"><a class="link--jss-0-686 adChoice--jss-0-685 ad-choice" rel="" href="javascript:void(0)" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=10.1.4.0">AdChoice</a></li></ul></div><div class="column--jss-0-681" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11"><h3 class="columnTitle--jss-0-682" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.0">Kijiji Support</h3><ul class="columnList--jss-0-683" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.1"><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.1.0"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.1.0.0">Help Desk</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.1.1"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/safety/safety-at-kijiji" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.1.1.0">Online Safety Tips</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.1.2"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.kijiji.ca/pages/pricechecker/" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=11.1.2.0">Price Checker</a></li></ul></div><div class="column--jss-0-681" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=12"><h3 class="columnTitle--jss-0-682" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=12.0">Kijiji Autos</h3><ul class="columnList--jss-0-683" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=12.1"><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=12.1.0"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="/t-dealer-registration.html" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=12.1.0.0">New Dealer Signup</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=12.1.1"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/policies/why-use-kijiji-autos" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=12.1.1.0">Dealer Help Pages</a></li></ul></div><div class="column--jss-0-681" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13"><h3 class="columnTitle--jss-0-682" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.0">Explore Kijiji</h3><ul class="columnList--jss-0-683" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1"><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.0"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/basics/benefits-of-registering" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.0.0">Kijiji Member Benefits</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.1"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://kijijiblog.ca/about-us/" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.1.0">About Kijiji</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.2"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="https://kijijiportraits.kijiji.ca" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.2.0">Kijiji Portraits</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.3"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="https://jobs.ebayinc.com/jobs?keywords=Kijiji&amp;lng=-79.4163&amp;lat=43.70011&amp;page=1&amp;location=Toronto,%20ON,%20Canada" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.3.0">Careers</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.4"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.ebayclassifiedsgroup.com/brands.html" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=13.1.4.0">eBay Classifieds Sites</a></li></ul></div><div class="column--jss-0-681" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14"><h3 class="columnTitle--jss-0-682" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.0">Frequently Asked Questions</h3><ul class="columnList--jss-0-683" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1"><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.0"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/basics/benefits-of-promoting-ads" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.0.0">How do I get people to see my Ad?</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.1"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/technical-issue/where-is-my-ad" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.1.0">Where is my Kijiji Ad? I can&#x27;t find it.</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.2"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/basics/editing-my-ad" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.2.0">How can I change my Ad?</a></li><li class="columnListItem--jss-0-684" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.3"><a class="link--jss-0-686" rel="nofollow" href="http://help.kijiji.ca/helpdesk/basics/deleting-my-ad" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.0.0.$=14.1.3.0">How do I delete my Ad?</a></li></ul></div></div></div><div id="FooterBadgeColumns" class="container--jss-0-690" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1"><div data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0"><div class="column--jss-0-691 storeColumn--jss-0-695" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=10"><a class="link--jss-0-692" href="https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/kijiji-free-local-classifieds/id318979520" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=10.0"><svg class="icon--jss-0-510" width="115" height="40" aria-labelledby="title" role="img" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=10.0.0"><title data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=10.0.0.0"></title><use xlink:href="#ios-app-store" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=10.0.0.1"></use></svg><span class="linkText--jss-0-694" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=10.0.1"></span></a></div><div class="column--jss-0-691 storeColumn--jss-0-695" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=11"><a class="link--jss-0-692" href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ebay.kijiji.ca" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=11.0"><svg class="icon--jss-0-510" width="115" height="40" aria-labelledby="title" role="img" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=11.0.0"><title data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=11.0.0.0"></title><use xlink:href="#google-play" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=11.0.0.1"></use></svg><span class="linkText--jss-0-694" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=11.0.1"></span></a></div><div class="column--jss-0-691" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=12"><a class="link--jss-0-692" href="http://kijijiblog.ca/" target="_blank" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=12.0"><svg class="icon--jss-0-510" width="40" height="40" aria-labelledby="title" role="img" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=12.0.0"><title data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=12.0.0.0"></title><use xlink:href="#rss-feed" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=12.0.0.1"></use></svg><span class="linkText--jss-0-694" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=12.0.1">Visit us on our Blog</span></a></div><div class="column--jss-0-691" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=13"><a class="link--jss-0-692" href="http://www.facebook.com/Kijiji.ca" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=13.0"><svg class="icon--jss-0-510" width="40" height="40" aria-labelledby="title" role="img" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=13.0.0"><title data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=13.0.0.0"></title><use xlink:href="#facebook" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=13.0.0.1"></use></svg><span class="linkText--jss-0-694" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=13.0.1">Friend us on Facebook</span></a></div><div class="column--jss-0-691" width="20%" style="width:20%;" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=14"><a class="link--jss-0-692" href="http://www.youtube.com/kijijicanadacorp" target="_blank" rel="nofollow" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=14.0"><svg class="icon--jss-0-510" width="40" height="40" aria-labelledby="title" role="img" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=14.0.0"><title data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=14.0.0.0"></title><use xlink:href="#youtube" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=14.0.0.1"></use></svg><span class="linkText--jss-0-694" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.1.0.$=14.0.1">Watch us on YouTube</span></a></div></div></div><div class="copyright--jss-0-705" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.2"><span data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.2.0">Copyright © 2016 eBay International AG. All rights reserved.</span><span class="fineprint--jss-0-706" data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc.0.2.1">Google, Google Play, YouTube and other marks are trademarks of Google Inc.</span></div></div></div><script type="text/javascript" id=".282hd8ogglc.script">
        if (!document.querySelector) throw new Error("react-dom-stream requires document.querySelector. If using IE8 or IE9, please make sure you are in standards mode by including <!DOCTYPE html>");
        document.querySelector('[data-reactid=".282hd8ogglc"]').setAttribute("data-react-checksum", -1685488400);
        var s = document.getElementById(".282hd8ogglc.script");
        s.parentElement.removeChild(s);
      </script></div>
            <script type="text/javascript">if(rehydrate===undefined){var rehydrate={};}rehydrate["footer"]={componentPath:"Shared/Footer",props:{}};</script>
          </div>
        <div class="modal-overlay"></div>


    <div id="FesLoader">

      <script type="text/javascript">window.__data="[\"~#iM\",[\"config\",[\"^0\",[\"toggleHeader\",false,\"showAdmarktLink\",false,\"showSearch\",true,\"toggleResponsive\",false,\"changeLocationURL\",null,\"searchForm\",[\"^0\",[\"attributeMap\",[\"^0\",[]],\"ll\",null,\"highlightOnly\",false,\"sortByName\",\"dateDesc\",\"adPriceType\",null,\"adIdRemoved\",null,\"maxPrice\",null,\"attributeFiltersMax\",[\"^0\",[]],\"userId\",null,\"origin\",null,\"categoryName\",\"\",\"keywords\",null,\"searchView\",\"LIST\",\"urgentOnly\",false,\"cpoOnly\",false,\"gpTopAd\",false,\"locationId\",0,\"radius\",\"\",\"attributeFiltersMin\",[\"^0\",[]],\"address\",\"Canada\",\"noLocation\",false,\"minPrice\",null,\"pageNumber\",1,\"categoryId\",null,\"locationPath\",\"0\",\"carproofOnly\",false]],\"adCount\",7479986,\"userLoggedIn\",false,\"language\",\"en\",\"targetUrl\",\"L3QtbG9naW4uaHRtbF5hQlNjOXlnVTkyelBsZjROYytCUXV3PT0-\"]],\"locationPicker\",[\"^0\",[]],\"postAd\",[\"^0\",[\"helpOffsetTop\",0,\"focusedStep\",null,\"loaded\",false,\"submitting\",false,\"steps\",[\"~#iL\",[]],\"isAsyncValid\",false,\"packages\",[\"^0\",[\"compare\",[\"^1\",[\"basic\",\"visibility\",\"maxVisibility\"]],\"frozen\",true,\"items\",[\"^0\",[\"basic\",[\"^0\",[\"id\",\"\",\"name\",null,\"heading\",null,\"subheading\",null,\"callout\",false,\"smallestMonthlyPrice\",0,\"showBenefits\",false,\"benefits\",[\"^1\",[]]]],\"hassleFree\",[\"^0\",[\"id\",\"PKG_HASSLE_FREE\",\"name\",null,\"heading\",null,\"subheading\",null,\"callout\",false,\"smallestMonthlyPrice\",null,\"showBenefits\",false,\"benefits\",[\"^1\",[]]]],\"visibility\",[\"^0\",[\"id\",\"PKG_VISIBILITY\",\"name\",null,\"heading\",null,\"subheading\",null,\"callout\",true,\"smallestMonthlyPrice\",null,\"showBenefits\",false,\"benefits\",[\"^1\",[]]]],\"maxVisibility\",[\"^0\",[\"id\",\"PKG_MAX_VISIBILITY\",\"name\",null,\"heading\",null,\"subheading\",null,\"callout\",false,\"smallestMonthlyPrice\",null,\"showBenefits\",false,\"benefits\",[\"^1\",[]]]]]],\"loaded\",false,\"selected\",null]],\"isValid\",false,\"isSyncValid\",false,\"editing\",false,\"fields\",[\"^0\",[\"category\",[\"^0\",[\"syncErrors\",[\"~#iS\",[]],\"errors\",[\"^2\",[]],\"hasErrors\",false,\"isAsyncValid\",true,\"isSyncValid\",true,\"isValid\",true]],\"description\",[\"^0\",[\"syncErrors\",[\"^2\",[]],\"errors\",[\"^2\",[]],\"hasErrors\",false,\"isAsyncValid\",true,\"isSyncValid\",true,\"isValid\",true]],\"postalCode\",[\"^0\",[\"syncErrors\",[\"^2\",[\"ad.validation.postalCode.postalCode\"]],\"errors\",[\"^2\",[\"ad.validation.postalCode.postalCode\"]],\"hasErrors\",false,\"isAsyncValid\",true,\"isSyncValid\",false,\"isValid\",false]],\"price\",[\"^0\",[\"syncErrors\",[\"^2\",[]],\"errors\",[\"^2\",[]],\"hasErrors\",false,\"isAsyncValid\",true,\"isSyncValid\",true,\"isValid\",true]],\"title\",[\"^0\",[\"syncErrors\",[\"^2\",[]],\"errors\",[\"^2\",[]],\"hasErrors\",false,\"isAsyncValid\",true,\"isSyncValid\",true,\"isValid\",true]]]],\"loading\",false,\"l1CategoryId\",null]],\"globalMessage\",null,\"suggestKeyword\",[\"^0\",[\"suggestions\",[\"^1\",[]],\"removed\",false,\"query\",\"\",\"categoryId\",0,\"selected\",false]],\"geolocation\",[\"^0\",[\"locationData\",[\"^1\",[]]]],\"cookies\",[\"^0\",[]],\"experiments\",[\"^0\",[\"optimizely\",[\"^0\",[]]]],\"phoneNumber\",[\"^0\",[\"phone\",null]],\"searchSuggest\",[\"^0\",[\"suggestions\",[\"^1\",[]],\"removed\",false,\"query\",\"\"]],\"i18n\",[\"^ \",\"get\",null,\"__version__\",1,\"data\",[\"^ \",\"en-CA\",[\"^ \",\"footer\",[\"^ \",\"columnTitles\",[\"^ \",\"information\",\"Kijiji Information\",\"support\",\"Kijiji Support\",\"autos\",\"Kijiji Autos\",\"explore\",\"Explore Kijiji\",\"faq\",\"Frequently Asked Questions\"],\"copyright\",[\"^ \",\"main\",\"Copyright © 2016 eBay International AG. All rights reserved.\",\"fineprint\",\"Google, Google Play, YouTube and other marks are trademarks of Google Inc.\"],\"faqLinks\",[\"^ \",\"link1\",[\"^ \",\"text\",\"How do I get people to see my Ad?\",\"href\",\"http:\u002F\u002Fhelp.kijiji.ca\u002Fhelpdesk\u002Fbasics\u002Fbenefits-of-promoting-ads\"],\"link2\",[\"^ \",\"^A\",\"Where is my Kijiji Ad? I can't find it.\",\"^B\",\"http:\u002F\u002Fhelp.kijiji.ca\u002Fhelpdesk\u002Ftechnical-issue\u002Fwhere-is-my-ad\"],\"link3\",[\"^ \",\"^A\",\"How can I change my Ad?\",\"^B\",\"http:\u002F\u002Fhelp.kijiji.ca\u002Fhelpdesk\u002Fbasics\u00
</html>
```

Comment: What is the response? What's in your `myContent` after that code runs?

Comment: How the response looks like? what are all the contents in the response? is that JSON or XML?

Comment: it is everything in between the <html> </html>.

Comment: what kind of application is this?

Comment: What do you mean? Are you asking me on what am I coding? @un-lucky

Comment: I mean, windows web or wpf

Comment: its console Application.

Comment: @Puzzle you're just retrieving the HTML content of this web page by running your code. You can't get back the value of a password from that website because that input for password has no value when you send a GET request to it and retrieve the HTML of the page.

Comment: I understand, that but I just gave that as an example. There is many other things that I could get also right. For example lets say I want the the value "fr_CA" which is part of the response. How can I get it? @mariocatch

Comment: I am pounding my head on the wall over this. It seems so simple but yet again I can't get it right. So irritating. @un-lucky

Comment: I am pounding my head on the wall over this. It seems so simple but yet again I can't get it right. So irritating. @mariocatch

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(myContent);
var r = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants();
var htmlTextBox = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name=="input" && x.Id=="login-password");
if (htmlTextBox != null)
{
    var passwordBoxHtml = htmlTextBox.OuterHtml;
}
```

Which gives you the output as `<input id="login-password" name="password" req="req" type="password" value="" maxlength="64">` in `passwordBoxHtml`.

For this you have to use `HtmlAgilityPack` which is available from [`nuget`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/)

Comment: Thank you for helping out. But I have already found the answer thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

If you want to retrieve a specific element's value, you would need to parse the content of the page you retrieved. There are plenty of packages out there that can parse HTML for you so you don't have to manually do it, such as HTML Agility: http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack

If you want to do it manually, hopefully this can get you started:

```
static void DownloadPage()
{
    CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();
    HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.CookieContainer = cookies;

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("https://www.kijiji.ca/t-login.html").Result)
        {
            HttpHeaders headers = response.Headers;
            HttpContent content = response.Content;
            string myContent = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            // Find value of ASOtherLang.
            //  It's in this pattern:
            //  <input type="hidden" id="ASOtherLang" value="fr_CA"/>
            Regex regex = new Regex("id=\"ASOtherLang\" value=\"(.*)\"");
            var otherLang = regex.Match(myContent).Groups[1];
            Console.WriteLine(otherLang);
        }
    }
}
```

---

It sounds like you're asking to retrieve the value of the password input by sending a GET request to a website. This cannot be done (unless there was a default value in that input).

The input you got back from your GET request is:

`<input id="login-password" name="password" req="req" type="password" value="" maxlength="64"/>`

There's nothing you can do with this that would yield you the password to login with.

Comment: I understand, that but I just gave that as an example. There is many other things that I could get also right. For example lets say I want the the value "fr_CA" which is part of the response. How can I get it? @mariocatch

Comment: @Puzzle I added a snippet that should hopefully get you started.

Comment: nice Got it with htmlAgilityPack. Thank you. @mariocatch